# regression algorithms for asymmetric losses

Tags: r, regression, python, loss-functions

I have a regression problem where over-predictions are better than under-predictions. I am now aware of Quantile Regression. Just wondering, which machine learning algorithms exist and/or can be adapted to deal with asymmetric losses? Any package suggestions in R or Python would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is example Python code that uses an asymmetric loss in the fitting (only) similar to what you describe.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.stats

xData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.0, 6.6, 7.7])
yData = numpy.array([1.1, 20.2, 30.3, 60.4, 50.0, 60.6, 70.7])


def func(x, a, b, c): # simple quadratic example
    return (a * numpy.square(x)) + b * x + c


def funcCustomLoss(xArray, a, b, c):
    returnList = []
    for i in range(len(xArray)):
        val = func(xArray[i], a, b, c)
        error = yData[i] - val
        if error < 0.0:
            val = val - (0.5 * abs(error))
        returnList.append(val)
    return returnList



initialParameters = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(funcCustomLoss, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```